# How to make a visual selection in vimscript given two (line, col) pairs?

Tags: vim

Given the following text in Vim:

```
ab
cde
```

And two positions like *from (line 1, col 3) to (line 2, col 4)*, how can I make a visual selection that covers them in Vimscript, including both ends?

Note *(line 1, col 3)* refers to the position **after** `b`, which is usually not selectable in normal mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual selection bounds are stored in `<` and `>` marks. `gv` in normal mode tells vim to enter visual mode using the `<` and `>` marks.

You can use `setpos()` to set a mark given a position. It expects the mark and a list of *(buffer number, line, column, offset)*. *offset* is used only with `:virtualedit`. The current buffer can be chosen using number 0.

```
call setpos("'<", [0, 1, 3, 0])
call setpos("'>", [0, 2, 4, 0])
normal! gv
```

Comment: Note that Vim versions before 7.3.590 cannot set the selection directly in this way. And you can just use `0` for the current buffer.